# Расширенные и обычные права доступа

Tags: unix

Что происходит с обычными(ugo/rwx) правами доступа, после установки дополнительныx (POSIX ACL)? Игнорируются ли они, учитываются ли частично...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принцип прост: если есть расширенные права доступа, они учитываются, а обычные права доступа не учитываются, если нет расширенных прав доступа, то учитываются обычные права доступа. Иначе говоря существует определенный порядок (приоритет) применения правил выставления прав (расширенные - обычные), первое применимое правило определяет выбор, последующие - не применяются.